# update trigger on a table to update same value to few other records in same table

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains some user id and their expiry date.

I want to create a trigger where , when I update a expiry date of a particular user , I need to set same expiry date for more users linked to above users in same table.

Can we do this.

Comment: Which database ?  What do you mean by "linked to the above users" ?  Technically, you would create a dml trigger, and when the new value for ExpDate is different than the old value, then run an additional update.  For any other solution you would need to add the table structure and the relation between the users' records, and what database it is.

Comment: Database I am using is SQL.

Comment: Sorry . database i am using is SQL, I have 2 type of users Main users , and sub-account under main users. say i maintain this data in sub-account table with coloums userid, parentid.  In other table i maintain user id and their expiry dates . User id can be both main and sub-accounts in this same table. when i extend the validity of a user , i need to update same validity of  for all sub-account taken from sub-accounts table

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not the name of a specific database product. All relational databases are "SQL databases".